# How do I get Nginx to redirect external traffic requests to a specific port on the 127.0.0.1 IP address of my Linux server?

Tags: nginx, redirect

I am using RHEL 8.x.  I have a web UI service listening on port 9200 of the 127.0.0.1 IP address.  I have installed Nginx.  I want Nginx to redirect web traffic to 127.0.0.1:9200.

From the back-end I ran this:  curl http://127.0.0.1:9200

It showed me what I expected.

From the front-end (via a web browser on my workstation) I can go to http://123.123.123.123 and see the default "Welcome to nginx..." web page.

I would expect after following a variety of different directions on configuring nginx.conf and restarting the nginx service would work for me.  It is merely showing the default "Welcome to nginx" page.  I want it to redirect traffic to a specific port on my Linux server.

I have tried variations of the server block in nginx.conf to be like this:

server {
    return 301 http://127.0.0.1:9200;
}

Or like this:

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 301 http://127.0.0.1:9200;
}

I tried modifying the location stanza and using proxy_pass.  I restart the Nginx server each time, but nothing seems to work.  How do I get Nginx to direct web traffic to the localhost over a specific port and bypass the default nginx web page?

Comment: You need to use proxy_pass. The config is really basic. My guess, you’ve spoiled browser cache with permanent redirect and now have to clear cache.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve.  It may help if you phrase your description in the form "When I do X, I want to see Y".  Please be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure nginx as [reverse proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/). Reverse proxy is proxy server (middleman) which sits in front of web server (in your case web UI server) and intercepts and forwards client traffic to it.

Basic nginx configuration for reverse proxy (just replace your default server { } block with this one)

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name _;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200/;
  }
}
```